# banning user ip through php or apache

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Our application uses MySQL to store every banned IP.
The IPs are banned automatically when certain events are triggered and they are added to the table `bans` for a given duration. The table is MyISAM, but very rarely an IP gets banned.

On each request that a player makes, we verify if his IP is among the banned IP's list and if his suspension is active. So sometimes this involves an useless DB request which influences the application's response time.

We were wondering if it wouldn't be a better choice to use APACHE and also write to file each banned IP, rather than performing an SQL query to verify if the IP of each visitor is among the banner IPs list.

How larger apps handle hundreds or thousands of banned IP's with many users active? Do they use databases or file writing?

Comment: Larger systems use hardware firewalls that are specifically designed for various purposes similar to this one.  Said firewalls take effect before the traffic even reaches the app.  Having said that, I'd go with database

Answer (score 3):

A database with a suitable index will be much faster than a simple file-based solution. If your response time is being affected by this query, something is very wrong with your code and/or database structure. If you need help with this, post your current code in a new question either here or preferably on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

With that said, depending on what you want to do with these banned users, you could look into [iptables](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-block-an-ip-on-my-linux-server/) which will block them from accessing your web server at all, thus removing the need for the query. There are a few libraries floating around that provide a PHP interface for this. Google "PHP iptables" for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If think you will end up banning thousands of IP. Then you must use database for speed. But if think at any time not more than 10-20 IP are banned you can choose to write in file. Banning from Apache is fast only when there are not too many IPs. Usually custom written function to verify IP are not efficient enough to be faster than database in searching through large number of IPs. I am talking in context of overall system resource use. But if you have no worries about eating up resources other than database then only writing in file can be justified.

Comment: Eventually yes, it may come to banning more than a thousand users.
Resources are important, so we will keep the database implementation.